# What happens to the stack when a value is moved in Rust?

Tags: rust, stack, move

Trying to wrap my head around the Rust ownership system and how the compiler implements it. Consider the following example:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let x = 5;
    let y = 3.7;

    function_that_takes_ownership(my_vec);
}

fn function_that_takes_ownership(Vec<i32> vec) {
    // ...
}
```

What actually happens to the stack memory occupied by `my_vec` when `function_that_takes_ownership` is called?

I guess, before the call the stack should look like this:

```
+-----------+
|    ...    |
+-----------+
|   my_vec  | // contains size, capacity and a pointer to heap
+-----------+
|     x     |
+-----------+
|     y     | 
+-----------+  <--- stack pointer points to here
```

What happens when `function_that_takes_ownership` is called? Is `my_vec` copy getting pushed to the stack again, while the old location is now considered unused? Or maybe a pointer to `my_vec` is actually getting pushed?